# A1314 wireless keyboard: 'y' and 'u' keys activating when keys above and below are pressed

Tags: macos, keyboard

As stated in the title, I have been recently been having problems with a A1314 wireless Apple keyboard.

The issue is that the '**y**' and '**u**' keys are activating themselves whenever I type any letters that are above them, or below them in the diagonal. For instance, letters **h, n, space bar, 6, and F5** activate the **y** key; letters **j, m, space bar, 7, and F6** activate the **u** key. Actually, for the case of letter **u**, whenever I press it, it **stays pressed** for random periods of time (also when I press the keys above or below it in the diagonal).

I have followed [this YouTube tutorial in order to clean "stuck keys"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HryU5nFV7X4&t=853s). However, this did not solve the problem. I have bought it second hand, so I do not know if there has been liquid damage before. Every other key works fine. Does this problem has a solution? Or is the keyboard dead?

Comment: I'd just send it straight back. It has some kind of short issue inside. It is not your responsibility to find or fix it. It was the seller's responsibility to advertise it as 'as seen, spares or repairs'.

Comment: @Tetsujin That is assuming that I bought it off from eBay or such... In my case, I found it at a flea market for about $2.50. I do not remember the face of the seller and it is unlikely that I will see him again. Fortunately I was able to make it work (although given the price, nothing was at stake here).

Answer (score 1):

I miraculously made it work after following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HryU5nFV7X4&t=853s) twice. The second time, since I did not have high hopes, I was a little more generous with the alcohol **and I took off every key**. So what worked for me was:

- took off **all of the keys and the plastic mechanism for each key**
- used a generous amount of alcohol to clean each spot (a little more than in the tutorial but without exaggerating either);
- used classic ethyl alcohol at 70%;
- submerge the keys and the mechanisms in soapy water (used dish soap) for one hour or so and rub with cloth afterwards;
- left it all to dry for 12 hours;
- placed the keyboard in front of a dehumidifier for about 15 minutes **before putting the keys back in place**.

For the last step, I am sure that direct sunlight for a fair amount of time would have worked as well, but the sky was cloudy that day in my case.

Additional notes: this keyboard was not particularly dirty or clogged with anything. There were eyelash/cat-like hair pieces in a "normal" amount and common dirt. What I did notice was some metallic glitter below the plastic mechanism in some keys, I do not know if these could be causing shorts or something similar... I took out as much as I could using tweezers at times.